# How to set heatmap aspect ratio

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, semantic-segmentation

I have a single-channel image where each integer pixel value maps to a string. For example 5 -> 'person'. I'm trying to create an interactive image where hovering over a pixel will display it's corresponding string.

I figured using plotly heatmaps might be the way to do this. The issues I'm having are:

- It's really slow. If I make my numpy array even (100,100) size it takes minutes to load. I'm thinking it might be because my code is not efficient?
- I can't figure out how to maintain aspect ratio. So if my image is a size (100,100) numpy array, I'd like the plot to also be (100,100) pixels.
- using blank values for `z_text` seems like a bad workaround, but setting `annotation_text=None` doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help me out here? Here's what I've got:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

z = np.random.randint(0,6, size=(10, 10))
z_text = np.full(z.shape, '', dtype=str)

d = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'e', 5:'f'}
class_mat = np.vectorize(d.get)(z)

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, annotation_text=z_text, text=class_mat, hoverinfo='text', colorscale='Viridis', )
fig.layout.title = 'Semantic Segmentation'

iplot(fig, filename='annotated_heatmap_text')
```

And here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

Also if a plotly heatmap is not the best way to go about this I'd love to hear any alternatives!

Note: I'm currently displaying inside jupyterlab.

Comment: @Austin How did my answer work out for you?

Comment: It was a while ago, but from what I remember it was too laggy for my use case. Although I'll select your answer since it seems to work on small cases

Comment: @Austin Was only the production of that particular laggy? Or the entire file/notebook?

Comment: iirc just the plot. The idea was to do it for an image of at least 100x100 pixels, so for that it wouldn't really work. Maybe that's just a limitation of plotly though, not quite sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've gotten every detail correct here, but the code in the snippet below will produce the following plot in a Jupyter Notebook. The line that handles the aspect ratio is:

```
fig['layout']['yaxis']['scaleanchor']='x'
```

You can also use:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis = dict(scaleanchor = 'x'))
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Plot 2:**

Just make sure to include:

```
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')
```

Or else you'll end up with this:

[image]

**Code 1 - My edits to your sample:**

```
fig.data[0]['hoverinfo'] = 'all'
fig['layout']['yaxis']['scaleanchor']='x'
fig['layout']['xaxis']['gridcolor'] = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
fig['layout']['yaxis']['gridcolor'] = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
fig['layout']['yaxis']['color'] = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
```

**Code 2 - The whole thing for an easy copy&paste:**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

#%qtconsole

z = np.random.randint(0,6, size=(10, 10))
z_text = np.full(z.shape, '', dtype=str)

d = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'e', 5:'f'}
class_mat = np.vectorize(d.get)(z)

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, annotation_text=z_text,
                                  text=class_mat, hoverinfo='text', colorscale='Viridis',
#                                   x = list('ABCDEFGHIJ'),
#                                   y = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
                                 )
fig.layout.title = 'Semantic Segmentation'

# My suggestions:
fig.data[0]['hoverinfo'] = 'all'
fig['layout']['yaxis']['scaleanchor']='x'

fig['layout']['xaxis']['gridcolor'] = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
fig['layout']['yaxis']['gridcolor'] = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
fig['layout']['yaxis']['color'] = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')

fig.show()
```

**Speed:**

Even this small figure takes some time to plot, but so far I do not have any suggestions on how to speed things up.

Comment: This is a very useful answer! 
Unfortunately, it does not seem to work correctly with subplots.
I have opened a new question to consider this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847142/ploty-heatmaps-in-subplots-how-to-set-aspect-ratio
(Sorry for posting it here initially as an answer.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you give heatmap is given x and y values (but you still want square pixels).

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are using `plotly.express.imshow` to plot the heatmap there is an argument to that function `aspect='auto'` that will update the aspect ratio to fill the space that the plot has.

For example:

```py
import plotly.express as px

# fill/load df accordingly to your needs

fig = px.imshow(df, aspect='auto')
```